# Documents.open affecting macro functionality?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a simplistic menu in word that opens a number of word files with various macros built in. Some of the macros function as normal when opened via the menu (e.g. forms that are showed on `Private Sub Document_Open`), but others (code to ignore warnings about saving in a macro free environment) are ignored.

Other issues, such as a debug errors about Word being 'unable to fire event', also seem to be occurring, but only when the files are opened via the menu. All the menu does is use `Documents.Open` and open the file.

When users open the file without the menu, no issues occur (no warnings about saving in a macro free environment, no errors about firing events).

Any help would be appreciated! I would prefer to not have to scrap the menu entirely for usability, as there are quite a few files that the menu serves as an index for.

Code below:

```
    If ComboBox1.Text = "- Full title page" Then
    Documents.Open ("A:/Workgroup Documents/Folder 1/templates/name of file.docm")
    End If
```

Code from document that is opened (***ThisDocument*** module):

```
 Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

 Option Explicit 

 Dim sDocName As String 
 Dim kcsval As String 

  Private Sub Document_Open() 
  frmFooters.Show 
  Set App = Word.Application 
  CATform.Show 
  On Error Resume Next 
  Documents("J:\Workgroup Documents\Edited Transcript\templates\menu.docm").Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
  FixSaveError 
  End Sub
```

Then some forms, and a module and class module that deal with the save error. Module:

```
 Option Explicit 

 Dim MyClass As New Class1 

 Sub FixSaveError() 
 Set MyClass.App = Word.Application 
 End Sub
```

Class module (***Class1***):

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
End Sub
```

The module and class module function purely to remove the warning message about saving in a macro-free environment when saving as docx from docm.

The forms that open up on `Document_Open` function fine, if it gets that far (the 'error firing event' error sometimes stops it getting there, but only sometimes and only on some machines - and *only* when using the menu to open the files).

Comment: In which code module is the code shown that has the `Document_Open` event code? Which code module is `MyClass`? What triggers the procedure `FixSaveError`? Which code is the class `App`? Why do you have `On Error Resume Next` in there with no further error handling?

Comment: @CindyMeister Document_Open event code is in the Microsoft Word Object of ThisDocument (so, the document itself, so to speak). MyClass is a class module called Class1 (Dim MyClass As New Class1), FixSaveError is triggered by document open (formatting in my post had it at the end of the line of code instead of on the line below, my bad). There is no class called App. 
On Error Resume Next without further error handling is just a way of dealing with the possibility of it erroring out when trying to close the document specified if it is not already open.

Comment: @Chris this is VBA, not .NET. I'm not familiar with any `Process.Start` in Word VBA?

Comment: I've never seen `Private WithEvents App As Word.Application` at the top of `ThisDocument`, which is why I asked the name of the class module containing `Document_Open`. Comment out/remove that as well as the `Set` line and `On Error Resume Next`. Also, change `ActiveDocument.Save` to `Doc.Save` (uses the `Doc` argument in the event call). Does that settle things down a bit?